# Nokogiri and XML - Grab "tr" XML that includes specific text

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Here is part of the word document that I'm looking to grab:

```
        <w:tr>
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:type="dxa" w:w="9035"/>
                    <w:tcBorders>
                        <w:top w:color="0A57A4" w:space="0" w:sz="6" w:val="single"/>
                    </w:tcBorders>
                    <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:p>
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:jc w:val="left"/>
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>#Finding#</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="49" w:name="_GoBack"/>
                    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="49"/>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:type="dxa" w:w="1705"/>
                    <w:tcBorders>
                        <w:top w:color="0A57A4" w:space="0" w:sz="6" w:val="single"/>
                    </w:tcBorders>
                    <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:noProof/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:drawing>
                            <wp:inline distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" distT="0">
                                <wp:extent cx="292608" cy="292608"/>
                                <wp:effectExtent b="0" l="0" r="0" t="0"/>
                                <wp:docPr id="924" name="Picture 924"/>
                                <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                                    <a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="1" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
                                </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                                <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                                        <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                                            <pic:nvPicPr>
                                                <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="S-sm.png"/>
                                                <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                                            </pic:nvPicPr>
                                            <pic:blipFill>
                                                <a:blip cstate="print" r:embed="rId20">
                                                    <a:extLst>
                                                        <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                                            <a14:useLocalDpi val="0" xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main"/>
                                                        </a:ext>
                                                    </a:extLst>
                                                </a:blip>
                                                <a:stretch>
                                                    <a:fillRect/>
                                                </a:stretch>
                                            </pic:blipFill>
                                            <pic:spPr>
                                                <a:xfrm>
                                                    <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                                                    <a:ext cx="292608" cy="292608"/>
                                                </a:xfrm>
                                                <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                                                    <a:avLst/>
                                                </a:prstGeom>
                                            </pic:spPr>
                                        </pic:pic>
                                    </a:graphicData>
                                </a:graphic>
                            </wp:inline>
                        </w:drawing>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
        </w:tr>
```

Is there a way to have nokogiri grab the entire `<w:tr>` all the way to the `</w:tr>` (the end) where "#Finding#" exists? Like have it search all "trs" for text that contains #Finding# and grab the entire tr element? Will I have to loop through each `<w:tr>` tag in the entire document and see if it contains #Finding# in it?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and "[ask]". We expect to see your attempts to solve the problem. That means showing what you searched and why it didn't help, or your code toward solving the problem. As is it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you, which isn't what SO is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have nokogiri grab the entire `<w:tr>` all the way to the `</w:tr>` (the end) where `"#Finding#"` exists?

XPath

```
//w:tr[.//w:t[contains(., '#Finding#')]]
```

In plain English *"any `<w:tr>` that has a `<w:t>` that contains `#Finding#`"*.

Notes:

- You must set up the `w` namespace prefix before you can use that XPath expression (its URI is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml`). See: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html
- Make sure that `#Finding#` does not contain single quotes, otherwise the expression will break.

Comment: Wow. Hit the nail right on the head. Very informative and thanks so much! Works like a charm!